# unreal engine development using vscode without vs2019, 2017

Tags: visual-studio-code, unreal-engine4

I'm wondering if I can make a C++ project in unreal engine without visual studio 2019, 2017 etc.

Currently I just use vscode. Is it necessary to install visual studio?

Comment: Unreal does have a bit of built in support for vs code. As with most things to do with UE4, the setup isn't officially documented but thankfully the steps are relatively simple and someone has provided them [here](http://jollymonsterstudio.com/2018/11/02/unreal-c-with-visual-studio-code/). (Obviously you'll still need a compiler and the requisite sdks)

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual studio code but you would need some compiler to compile your C++ project. For that the MSVC compiler that visual studio supports is often used. You can download the MSVC compiler and use visual studio code with it. when you create your project with visual studio code  will generate a **.vscode** folder. **In this folder you will have a**

- task.json [ for generating the build scripts you need to compile your program and create the exe files]
- Launch.json [ for debugging your C++ classes]
- Properties.json [ for finding the MSVC compiler ]

Unreal engine has a button in the editor that will compile your code. This equivalent to running

```
cd " Where you have your engine installed" 

"Engine\\Build\\BatchFiles\\Build.bat" YourProjectNameEditor Win64 Development "C:\ThePathToYourProject\YourProjectName.uproject" -waitmutex
```

Visual studio provides other build task such as a DebugBuildGame and ShippingBuild
Visual studio code also provides these build task through task.json file, but it does not work out of the box
I ended up making a video about this and timestamped important events

https://youtu.be/fydvKedIxKk

You want to consider fixing the task.json if your want to run any build other than the editor one.

Comment: Which is better for Unreal Engine? Visual Studio or VS Code? 
I know, both will have their own strengths. I personally want to use VS Code, but I fear that I might miss out very good features